# height enimation slow only in firefox

Tags: performance, firefox

I wrote some js to always keep a container div of a certain height by making sure
that it's children div heights always amount to the same amount. But it's slow in ff!
Run [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mLa46/) in chrome, ie and ff please.
You should see it run up to 6x slower in firefox.
Any ideas why or how to fix it?

I'd also be happy with and alternative solution to my problem.

Here is the code I use:

```
var timeout;
var stripHeight = 80;
var stripHeightClick = 300;
var duration = 500;

Element.prototype.setHeight = function (set) {
    this.style.height = set + "px";
};

Element.prototype.addHeight = function (add) {
    this.style.height = (parseInt(this.style.height) + add) + "px";
};

Element.prototype.getHeight = function () {
    var style = getComputedStyle(this);
    return parseInt(style.height);
};

window.resize = function (self){
    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    var fc = document.getElementById("fc");
    fc.innerHTML = 0;
    var hoverElement = self;
    clearTimeout(container.resizeTimeout);
    hoverElement.isDone = false;
    var heightDiff = stripHeightClick - hoverElement.getHeight();
    var startTime = new Date().getTime();
    var timeElapsed = 0;
    var increment = 0;
    var oldHeight = hoverElement.getHeight();
    var newHeight;
    var shrinkLastIndex = 0;
    var elementsToShrink = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < container.children.length; i++) {
        if (container.children[i] !== hoverElement && container.children[i].getHeight() > stripHeight) {
            elementsToShrink.push(container.children[i]);
            container.children[i].isDone = false;
        }
    }

    container.resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function loop() {
        if (timeElapsed < duration) {
            var timeElapsedPercentage = (timeElapsed / duration);
            var newHeight = (Math.round(timeElapsedPercentage * heightDiff) + oldHeight);
            var increment = newHeight - hoverElement.getHeight();
            hoverElement.style.height = newHeight + "px";
        } else {
            increment = stripHeightClick - hoverElement.getHeight();
            hoverElement.style.height = stripHeightClick + "px";
        }

        var rem = increment % elementsToShrink.length;
        var dec = increment - rem;
        if (dec - rem > 0) {
            dec /= elementsToShrink.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < elementsToShrink.length; i++) {
                elementsToShrink[i].addHeight(-dec);
            }
        }
        if (rem > 0) {
            for (var i = shrinkLastIndex; dec > 0;
            (i + 1 < elementsToShrink.length) ? i++ : i = 0) {
                elementsToShrink[i].addHeight(-1);
                shrinkLastIndex = (i + 1 < elementsToShrink.length) ? i + 1 : 0;
                dec--;
            }
        }

        //frame count update
        fc.innerHTML = parseInt(fc.innerHTML)+1;

        if (!(timeElapsed < duration)) {
            hoverElement.isDone = true;
            return;
        }
        timeElapsed = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
        container.resizeTimeout = setTimeout(loop.bind(hoverElement), 0);
    }.bind(hoverElement), 0);
}
```

Comment: Works just as fast for me on Chrome & FF (Windows 7 64 bit, latest browser versions).

Comment: same os. ie11 up to 150, chrome 90, firefox 24. Is it just me then?